# How to get create() return auto-increment primary key after creation in sails.js?

Tags: mysql, sails.js

I have a model, Case.js:

```
...
attributes: {
    id: {
        type: 'integer',
        unique: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        columnName: 'pid' //an auto-increment primary key, generated by MySQL
    },
    ...
}
```

And I want to get this id after creation:

```
Case.create({...}).then(function(aCase){
    console.log(aCase.id);
})
```

The creation succeeded, but the output I got is undefined.
I tried setting autoPK to false, and deleting "unique" and "primaryKey" entry, but the result didn't change.
Please tell me how to make create() return this id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've worked it out myself. The problem lies in my model Case.js.
In sails.js, if you want a primary key (usually id) created by MySQL with auto-increment to be returned after create(), your model should look like this:

```
module.exports = {
    ...
    autoPK: false,
    attributes: {
        id: {
            type: 'integer',
            unique: true,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true,
        },
        ...
    }
}
```

Pay attention to "autoIncrement" attribute, it is necessary in my case, and probably in every auto-increment primary key.

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking at the [Sails.js documentation](http://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/models/create) for creating a new entry in a database. The method is indicated as

```
Something.create(values).exec(function (err, records) {

});
```

In your case, you should have

```
Case.create({...}).exec(function(err, aCase){
    console.log(aCase.id);
})
```

Comment: In fact, then() is a method in es6-promise. Simply speaking, my code using then() has the same effect as your code using exec(). 
Still, I tried exec() just now, and the result didn't change: creation succeeded, but no id returned.

Comment: What database adapter are you using? PostgreSQL? Mongo?

Comment: sails-mysql@0.11.5

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure where to direct you from here.